# How to modify my code to get all non-unique values?

Tags: javascript

With duplicates, this code worked fine

```
const findDuplicates = (word) => {
    let arr = word.toLowerCase();
    let sorted_arr = [...arr].slice().sort();
    console.log(sorted_arr); 
    let results = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < sorted_arr.length - 1; i++) {
      if (sorted_arr[i + 1] == sorted_arr[i]) {
        results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
      }
    }
    return results;
}

console.log(findDuplicates('piccdda123dd'));
```

Output

```
[
  '1', '2', '3', 'a',
  'c', 'c', 'd', 'd',
  'd', 'd', 'i', 'p'
]
[ 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd' ]
```

How to modify if condition to deal with multiple non-unique values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something like this we should be gunning for constant time `0(n)`. Sorting is going to give us `O(nlogn)` at best and is not required.

```
function findDuplicates(s) {
    const seen = {};
    const result = [];

    for (let c of s.toLowerCase())  {
        if(c in seen) {
            result.push(c);
        }
        seen[c] = true; // could be any value doesn't have to be boolean.
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(findDuplicates('piccdda123dd'));
```

result

```
[ 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd' ]
```

We just need to iterate over the string once and keep a map object (could use es6 `Set`) that tells us if we've seen this value before. If we see it again and it's already been seen we can append it to the `result` array.

If you wanted to see each duplicated character only once try

```
function findDuplicates2(s) {
    const seen = {};

    for (let c of s.toLowerCase())  {
        const ent = seen[c];
        seen[c] = (ent === undefined) ? 1 : ent + 1;
    }

    return Object.entries(seen).filter(([k,v]) => v > 1).map(([k,v]) => k);
}

console.log(findDuplicates2('piccdda123dd'));
// prints ['c', 'd']
```

Comment: If you use a number instead of a boolean value you could increase it on each hit and you would automatically get the number of occurences.

Comment: yeah sure I wrote [another version](https://pastebin.com/t3S6Uhkw) which does that but for this example I just wanted to keep it simple.

Comment: Okay, just because this is normally the immediate next question. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED.

```
const findDuplicates = (word) => {
    let arr = word.toLowerCase();
    let sorted_arr = [...arr].slice().sort();
    console.log(sorted_arr); 
    let results = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < sorted_arr.length - 1; i++) {
      if (sorted_arr[i + 1] == sorted_arr[i]) {
          if (!results.includes(sorted_arr[i]))
        results.push(sorted_arr[i]);
      }
    }
    return results;
}
```

ES6 includes IS REALLY powerfull.

Comment: bruuuuuuuuuuuuh

Comment: @TheBombSquad What the f.?

Comment: I mean you could just use an object and then output the keys of the object.. less complexity.. also i said bruh because if u answered it so fast means u didnt really try

Comment: or just replace `return results;` with  `return [...new Set(results)];`